# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File stock_dfs/BRK.B.csv does not exist: how to adjust code if file doesn't exist:

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
import bs4 as bs
import datetime as dt
import os
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pickle
import requests


def save_sp500_tickers():
resp = 
requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})
tickers = []
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    ticker = row.findAll('td')[0].text
    tickers.append(ticker)
with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(tickers, f)
return tickers


 # save_sp500_tickers()
def get_data_from_yahoo(reload_sp500=False):
if reload_sp500:
    tickers = save_sp500_tickers()
else:
    with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "rb") as f:
        tickers = pickle.load(f)
if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs'):
    os.makedirs('stock_dfs')

start = dt.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime.now()
for ticker in tickers:
    # just in case your connection breaks, we'd like to save our progress!
    if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
        df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
        df.reset_index(inplace=True)
        df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
        df = df.drop("Symbol", axis=1)
        df.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
    else:
        print('Already have {}'.format(ticker))


def compile_data():
with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "rb") as f:
    tickers = pickle.load(f)

main_df = pd.DataFrame()

for count, ticker in enumerate(tickers):
    df = pd.read_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
```

**error occurs here it states "File stock_dfs/BRK.B.csv does not exist" but it wasnt imported / stored locally in the first place so why is this an issue? full error at the bottom**

```
    df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

    df.rename(columns={'Adj Close': ticker}, inplace=True)
    df.drop(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'], 1, inplace=True)

    if main_df.empty:
        main_df = df
    else:
        main_df = main_df.join(df, how='outer')

    if count % 10 == 0:
        print(count)
print(main_df.head())
main_df.to_csv('sp500_joined_closes.csv')


compile_data()
```

pandas_datareader\compat__init__.py:7: FutureWarning: pandas.util.testing is deprecated. Use the functions in the public API at pandas.testing instead.
  from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal
0
10
20
30
40
50
60
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Python tutorials\Python finance Examples\py3tutorialSP500manip.py", line 75, in 
    compile_data()
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Python tutorials\Python finance Examples\py3tutorialSP500manip.py", line 57, in compile_data
    df = pd.read_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 448, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 880, in **init**
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1114, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1891, in **init**
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 374, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.**cinit**
  File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 674, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File stock_dfs/BRK.B.csv does not exist: 'stock_dfs/BRK.B.csv'

following this tutorial:

https://pythonprogramming.net/combining-stock-prices-into-one-dataframe-python-programming-for-finance/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right before the error occurs, a call is made to `pd.read_csv()`:

```py
for count, ticker in enumerate(tickers):
    df = pd.read_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
```

The error occurs when `ticker` is `'BRK.B'` and the program attempts to set **read** data from `'stocks_dfs/BRK.B.csv'`.

The error message is saying that there is no `stocks_dfs/BRK.B.csv` file on your machine. This is puzzling since this bit of code should have **downloaded** all the necessary files:

```py
for ticker in tickers:
    # just in case your connection breaks, we'd like to save our progress!
    if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
        df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
        df.reset_index(inplace=True)
        df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
        df = df.drop("Symbol", axis=1)
        df.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
    else:
        print('Already have {}'.format(ticker))
```

Make sure you ran the **download** code (directly above) in the same directory you are running the **read** code (top). To run a quick check, see if there exists a folder called `stock_dfs/` in you working directory. That folder should contain files like `GOOGL.csv`, `FB.csv`, and specifically **`BRK.B.csv`**.

Comment: Absolutely! I'm glad that I was able to help you out. Please consider marking correct + accepting, I would really appreciate it. :)